# Are true random values generated in the past and stored still considered random?

Tags: random, prng

Pretend I have a client service that needs true random Integer values (4 bytes) every 10 seconds.

As such, I acquire a piece of hardware that generates true random values based on atmospheric noise. The device can generate up to 8 bytes of random data per second.

As I stand now, every 10 seconds, my client service can query the device, and pull 4 bytes out of the 8 generated bytes. The value is used by the client service instantly, and is considered true random.

Now pretend I instantiate 3 new client services (total of 4), running the same algorithm. The services are all synchronized together, so they will query the device at the same time.

What happens now is that, at the 10 second mark, only 2 of the services (out of 4) will receive a random value immediately, and the other 2 services will have to wait up to 1 full second before receiving their value. This is undesirable.

Since I'd rather maximize the use of my expensive device, I come up with this solution: the software sitting on the server (where the device is connected) will actually be collecting all values from the device, and store them in a queue (which will be dequeued automatically if it grows too big for the RAM). Now, when a client service makes a query, the random value will be dequeued from that queue instead of pulled directly from the device. Like before, each random value is only used once, but in this case, some of the values in the queue could have been sitting there for a long time.

I fear that I might be doing things the wrong way with this solution. I can't shake off the nagging feeling that, using a value that was generated in the past, and is not 'fresh', I am somehow turning this back into a pseudo-random generator. Are my fears correct, or unsubstantiated?

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest...

Comment: If I roll a dice then close my eyes for a few seconds, then look to see what I rolled. Is that roll no longer random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the day, the only thing that matters is that your `random` function produces a sequence of statistically random values.

To that end, it doesn't matter whether your implementation gets the values one at a time, or all at once and puts them in a queue. As long as they are sufficiently random, they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Colonel Thirty Two. It's not as if the client services can pick and choose a specific time or value that they would like to use. As long as the value has not already been used it shouldn't be an issue.

Something that you could do is clear your generated value after all 4 devices have requested a new value from the device. Since you said that they were all connected and querying at the same time, this should be every 10 seconds. That should be an ample amount of time to generate at least 4 new random numbers.